# CUDA C : I need to fix deviations from my serial program

Tags: cuda, atomic

So I have a very basic 2D cellular automata program. The tricky part, or at least why I turned to learning GPU programming, is that my matrices tend to be a minimum of 100 million elements. I have made what I might call a naive implementation ( 1st draft ) of my serial program into CUDA C. It works great, but I think I see a way to improve it further.

For testing purposes it is necessary that I keep track of the live cell counts ( in my implementation live cells are represented by 1's, and dead cells by 0's ) between each iteration on the matrices. In my 1st draft the host is responsible for the N^2 nested loops of counting the live cells after the device is finished updating the matrix.

Here is some pseudo code to give you a better idea ( the following code is itself inside of a loop that terminates after an arbitrary number of iterations ):

```
cuda_kern<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( d_grid );
cudaMemcpy( h_grid, d_grid, matrixSize*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

*liveCell = 0;
for(a=0; a<gridLength; a++)
    for(b=0; b<gridLength; b++)
        if(h_grid[a][b]==1) (*liveCell)++;

printf("live cell count is %d\n", *liveCell);
```

As you can see I have two rather costly operations on my hands. First, I have to transfer my matrix ( referred to as grids above ) between device and host on each iteration. Secondly I have the N^2 operation of combing/counting the matrix for live cell counts. I believe I can eliminate both of these steps by transferring only the live cell count between host and device on each iteration. In fact, I'm very close to having this coded, but as the question title indicates there are slight 'random' deviations from a confirmed live count from my serial program, and my latest CUDA program.

Here is some pseudocode from my 2nd draft kernel:

```
__global__ void cuda_kern( liveCell, grid )
{
    i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x
    j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y

    if( i < gridLength AND j < gridLength )
    {
        __shared__ int temp[number of threads in block] 
        x, y, count, changeCounter, sum = 0

        // nested for loops here that update int variable 'count'
        // for those familiar with CA it is a basic neighborhood analysis
        for x to arbitrary neighborhood range
            for y to arbitrary neighborhood range
            {
                //count neighbors, that is update 'count' variable
            }

        // __syncthreads()

        if( grid[i*gridLength+j] == 0 AND count == 5 ) 
        { // NOTE: 'count' above could be any arbitrary integer 1 - 8  
            grid[i*gridLength+j] = 1
            changeCounter += 1
        }
        else if( grid[i*gridLength+j] ==  1 AND count >= 5 )
        {
            grid[i*gridLength+j] = 0
        }
        else 
        {
            grid[i*gridLength+j] = 1
            changeCounter += 1
        }

        //__syncthreads()

        temp[threadIdx.x] = changeCounter 

        //__syncthreads()

        if (threadIdx.x == 0)
            for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
            { 
                sum += temp[i]
                //__syncthreads()
            }

        atomicAdd( liveCell, sum )

    } // end of if ( i < gridLength and j < gridLength )   
    return;
} // end of kernel
```

Explanation of above pseudocode: 
I have tried to leave out the non-essentials, such as the majority of the logic behind the cellular automata functions. All of the variables are integers in my program, and the matrix itself is of type integer. I have left in comments the places where I have tried to synchronize the threads ( to no avail ).

Explanation of my logic:
As mentioned previously when discussing my first draft implementation, I want to avoid the costly operations of transferring my matrix between device and host and the N^2 cost of counting the live cells on the host for each iteration. The key to doing this can be seen with the variable 'changeCounter.' Essentially 'changeCounter' should be incremented by one every time a cell is designated as '1' or alive. I'm attempting to use a **shared** variabled 'temp' that is indexed by the current thread to store the value of 'changeCounter.' Once all of the threads within a block are finished, I'm then attempting to condense the 'temp' array into a single variable 'sum', which I then add to liveCell via the atomic operation 'atomicAdd.'

The problem I'm having is that my results with this method (while faster) don't match my original drafts results, and also every time I run the program on the same matrix there is a slight deviation in each iteration of the live cell count.

**UPDATE**
Example Outputs on a 1k by 1k matrix:

The 1st Draft GPU implementation produces the following live cell counts every time. These are the results I wish to produce with my 2nd draft.

```
initial live cell count: 393592 
itr. 0  live cell count: 364118
itr. 1  live cell count: 315417
itr. 2  live cell count: 300413 
itr. 3  live cell count: 284503
```

The 2nd Draft GPU implementation live cell counts vary slightly each time, but are close to above. Here are three separate runs to give you an idea.

**Run A:**

```
initial live cell count: 393592
itr. 0  live cell count: 372402
itr. 1  live cell count: 324114
itr. 2  live cell count: 309580
itr. 3  live cell count: 291393
```

**Run B:**

```
initial live cell count: 393592
itr. 0  live cell count: 374139
itr. 1  live cell count: 323948
itr. 2  live cell count: 307214
itr. 3  live cell count: 292582
```

**Run C:**

```
initial live cell count: 393592
itr. 0  live cell count: 372391
itr. 1  live cell count: 323105
itr. 2  live cell count: 308295
itr. 3  live cell count: 292512
```

The initial live cell count is calculated on the host each time, which explains why it is consistent across all of the examples.

**END OF UPDATE**

Thank you for your time. If you need anymore information please let me know.

Comment: I haven't looked for the bug, but, instead of having your entire kernel inside a conditional, consider using a inverted conditional with a return statement at the top. Also, using an atomicAdd() is not going to be a good solution as all your threads will be serialized during the atomicAdd() instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not do this:

```
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
        { 
            sum += temp[i]
            //__syncthreads()
        }
        atomicAdd( liveCell, sum )// could probably just update the memory without atomic
    }
```

As you said that all threads in the block calculate their sum, then you with thread 0 sum up all threads sum, then you should add that to the pointer specified. If every thread does an atomicAdd it will be different, you should probably do it only with thread 0, and you can probably remove the atomic operation.

Also, do reduction on that loop:

```
for (i=blockDim.x/2; i>0; i>>=1) {
     if(threadIdx.x < i) {
         temp[threadIdx.x] += temp[threadIdx.x + i];
     }
    __syncthreads();
}
if(threadIdx.x == 0) {
    sum = temp[0];
    liveCell += sum;
}
```

Comment: There's only a single statement there, so brackets make no difference at all.  Also, that's pseudocode.

Comment: I appreciate the response, however the above did not solve my problem. I'll add some more information to the question.